# setup ansible-jupyter-kernel -> No module named ansible_runner

Tags: ansible, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble setting up ansible-jupyter-kernel. The error is:

`ImportError: No module named ansible_runner`

My setup:

I use miniconda with a minimal environment with the following packages:

```
  - ipykernel
  - jupyter
  - python >=2.7,<2.8
  - pip:
    - ansible-jupyter-widgets
    - ansible-kernel==0.9.0
```

Normally I use jupyterlab with python 3, but I was having the same issue and the Dockerfile from the ansible-jupyter-kernel repo called for the notebook and python2.

With the environment specified above I do the following:

```
python -m ansible_kernel.install --sys-prefix
jupyter notebook --no-browser --debug --ip=0.0.0.0
```

Here is the full error from stdout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/df115/projects/ansible/envs/_default/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/df115/projects/ansible/envs/_default/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/df115/projects/ansible/envs/_default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible_kernel/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .kernel import AnsibleKernel
  File "/home/df115/projects/ansible/envs/_default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible_kernel/kernel.py", line 43, in <module>
    import ansible_runner
ImportError: No module named ansible_runner
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Uh, isn't it just `pip install ansible-runner` as explained in [the fine manual](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/install.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew L Daniel is absolutely correct.

Sorry, I was thinking that ansible-runner was part of ansible-kernel. I didn't realize it was its own software package. I should have googled "ansible-runner" by itself.

Thank you!